# Android Studio 2.3 error: "Gradle sync failed: Cause: services.gradle.org"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After I open a new project in Android Studio 2.3, I receive an error such as:

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: services.gradle.org

Googling just gave me a log file on an issue tracker page. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling. I am not behind a proxy and I've already set:

```
Use default gradle wrapper
```

Restarting Gradle sync stops at

> Refreshing Gradle project

I can't find anything to fix this problem.
I am running Android Studio on Windows 8.1 with JRE 1.8.0

Comment: Provide info about build gradle file top-level build file where you have added configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

Comment: Is Offline-Work disabled in Android Studio settings?

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: I disabled "Offline-work" under File -> Settings -> Build,Exec,Deploy... -> Gradle
which fixed the above mentioned issue, but it led me further to another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841660/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-p for which I'm not able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. You have two ways to solve this.

First one is to connect to the Internet and download a new version of Android Studio and the required packages.

Note: You should have "proxies" and "offline work" options enabled.

The second way is to go to `file > settings > build > gradle` and do the following:

1. Uncheck the "offline work" option.
2. Use local gradle distribution and then set the path.

Note: When you have "no proxy" option checked with "offline work" then you have to provide path for every new project.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess This Can Help You.....
https://gradle.org/install

// for manual installation
to get the gradle distribution visit

https;//gradle.org/release

STEPS

1 Dowmload the gradle

2 unzip the pack.

3 create a new folder in your C drive and name it gradle

4 place the unzipped pack into the folder you created

5 Now set the path for your gradle in Android Studio to the just created folder

6 Add the path of your gradle to the System Varaibles.

7 Computer, right click >Properties>Advance System Settings>Enviroment 
Varaibles>System Varaibles.Path>Edit.

Hope its Helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. so i followed this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#installation 
finally i got it !!

Android Stidio v 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and have tried reinstalling to no avail.

What I found was useful is to look in my home directory (on Ubuntu) and open the .gradle folder and open the matching sub folder and delete the lck file and then manually download the desired gradle version (url distributionUrl value) and place the downloaded file in the folder that had the lck file.

Have attributed this problem to using usb tethering for internet..

[image]