# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-P'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api, android-9.0-pie

I'm following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java/#1) tutorial page

and i get the exact same error that they say in that page

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-P' in: D:\Development\Android\Sdk
>   Install missing platform(s) and sync project

[image]

when i click

**install missing platform(s) and sync project** 
it shows the error as

[image]

> All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
>   - Package id platforms;android-P

[image]

[image]

I have installed almost all the SDK it asks for ANDROID - P.

Answer (score 4):

you're trying to find a SDK that corresponds to the version "android-p".
Have a look at your build.gradle file:

`android {
compileSDKVersion 'android-p'
..........
}`

change it to

`android {
compileSDKVersion 28
..........
}`

note that the version 28 is just one example, you could be using any version.

that should do the job for you.

Comment: Thank u for the reply, but still, doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue is ralated to checksums in repositories.
Take a look at this answear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842352

Comment: Thank u for the reply, but still, doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer of [Bevilaqua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911135/10041106)

Then, a dialog poped to make a Gradle Plugin Update :
[Android Gradle Plugin Update Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXkaE.png)

Of course, it failed :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHGLG.png)

So, to fix it, I manually installed a recent version of Gradle from [enter link description here](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/) in my **.gradle** folder (in Windows `C:\Users\...\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`)

And I got another problem because a these line in styles.xml : 
`<style name="Widget.Shrine.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox">` where I replaced **OutlineBox** by **OutlinedBox** :
`<style name="Widget.Shrine.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">`
([Source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/148))

Now, everything is functional.